# Download GPM-IMERG satellite images in R

Tags: r, gis, gdal, installation-package

I've been trying (a lot) to download [NASA's GPM-IMERG satellite images with precipitation data](https://pmm.nasa.gov/GPM) from R. I'm doing the question in this forum and not in the GIS forum because I read that most [r](/questions/tagged/r) users are here. (FYI: Im running Windows 10 and [r](/questions/tagged/r) `3.6.3` in [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio)). So far I've tried the following:

1. Created an account at PMM-NASA (see [here](https://pmm.nasa.gov/data-access/downloads/gpm)). Everything worked well.
2. Installed the `gpm` package from `devtools::install_github("csaybar/gpm")`, followed by 
   `gpm_getaxel()` (see [here](https://github.com/csaybar/gpm)). I tried running the following code.

```
    gpm_download(path = RutaDownloads,
                     user = "myuser@email.com",
                     password = "myuser@email.com",
                     dates = c('2017-01-01','2017-02-28'),
                     band = 3,
                     lonMin = 70,
                     lonMax = 75,
                     latMin = 34,
                     latMax = 38, 
                     product = 'finalrun',
                     quiet = F,
                     n = 1)
```

However, it did not worked. The error shown in [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) is the following.

> ```
> 'gdal_translate' not found Error in gdaltranslate_exist() :    GDAL
> should be declared as a system variable if you are using Windows
> ```

I haven't had any problems running `gdal` when working with multiple [rasters](/questions/tagged/rasters)/vectors in R (so far). Does anyone know if I have to install [gdal](/questions/tagged/gdal) in my PC apart from installing `rgdal` in [r](/questions/tagged/r)? If so, how can I do it and 'synchronize' it with R to be used with `gpm` package? I know there is a lot of information in google, however, I'd rather take the advice from anyone that has done this before, because in the past I did not have such a good experience working, for example, with GDAL and Python, and that is the main reason I started working my GIS codes in R.

3. I also tried with another alternative installing the `remotes` package and `remotes::install_github("bastianmanz/GPM_rain")` (See [here](https://github.com/bastianmanz/GPM_rain/)). However, this uses the `rhdf5` package, which is not available for my R version, and thus I installed the `BiocManager` and then `BiocManager::install("rhdf5")` (following the instructions from [here](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/rhdf5.html)). With `GPM_rain` there are two possible ways to download the images: (1) with `wget` i.e. `system_download`, but its not straightforward because it needs a list of the files to download, and (2) with `rcurl_download` using `RCurl`. This seemed easy to use. Nevertheless, the first problem is that I cannot specify lat/long for the image extent and, as in point 2, it did not work. I tried running the following code:

```
rcurl_download(product = "nrt",
               nrt_type = "late",
               start = 20170101,
               end = 20170131,
               userpwd = "myuser@email.com:myuser@email.com")
```

But the error says that `rcurl_download`function was not found. **How to fix any of the above errors or have any other solutions, I would be really grateful if you could share your experience, specially for option 2**, where I can set lat/long to download the data. Thanks in advance,
Jorge.

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**EDIT:**

- Package `gpm` is "retired" according to its developer ([see here](https://github.com/csaybar/gpm/issues/4)).

Comment: Dear massisenergy,

I have the same problem as you when I launch the command "gpm_download" (GDAL should be declared as a system variable if you are using Windows). Did you find a solution to this! and you have found a command line which allows you to better download the images from the gpm database! Thank you

Comment: Hello @tazrart, If I happen to get a working solution Ill post it here... Im stuck with that. Hopefully someone will help :D cheers,

Comment: Hello @Jorge V . Try to install "GDAL" separately and normally it should work. Gdal download link : https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows

Comment: @tazrart thank you for your answer. I did something like that a couple of weeks ago and worked. The problem now is that `gpm` package is retired. And thus (as far as I know) the only possibility is to download via `rcurl`, which I haven't been able to do it yet.